# Can I overload the update function of SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am wondering, if I can overload the update function in SpriteKit, so that my program begins lagging because of that? (thus it is called quite often -> every frame or something)

I am checking variables inside the update function saying like:

```
func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
{
    if(isLeveldone)
    {
        createNewLevel()
    }
}
```

I am setting the isLeveldone:Bool to false inside the createNewLevel function, so it wont start the function every update.
And of those checks, I have like 6 or 7.

Comment: What does `createNewLevel` do? This actually looks like far too little code in `update` for a working program, even one that is still being developed. Is there more to it than you are showing? Also, are you seeing the lag in the simulator or n a real device.? Simulator performance is a very poor indicator of real device performance.

Comment: Yes I figured my problem, it was because some actions were fired by NStimers and the timers are not that precise I think

Comment: Don't use NSTimers - the SK engine doesn't understand them. y which I mean that it doesn't know they are running and they can interfere with things (for example, if you ever `pause` your gameScene, the NSTimers won pause and will keep running). Use `SKActions` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by ‘overload’ your mean ‘get it to do too much work’, rather than the object-orientated programming definition of ‘overload’, then yes, you can.

However - you can do a *lot* of work in ‘update‘ before it starts to be a problem. What you have doesn’t look enough to cause your program to lag, unless your `createNewLevel` function is huge.

Note: Swift does support 'overloading' in the OOP sense i.e. defining a function several times but with different signatures (parameter types), but this isn't applicable to `update` (which was not what you were asking, I realise) because `update` is only ever called by the SK engine, and you shouldn't attempt to call it yourself.

Comment: yes thats what i meant by overload thanks ; its not that huge so I guess I wont have any problems